# Problems with my layout

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, textview

I have some FrameLayouts in a Relative Layout. In the FrameLayouts there are some TextViews. I want those textviews to be either in the center or top left. The problem is, that I can't figure it out how to do this... 
It currently looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJSz2.png
(Sorry for the link)

This is my layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.timbremer.ctdataviewer.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:padding="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:background="#eeeeee"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



<FrameLayout
android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
android:layout_height="117dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Verbrauchtes Volumen:"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bitte aktualisieren."
    android:id="@+id/tvused"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
    android:layout_height="117dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:text="Gesamtvolumen:"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bitte aktualisieren."
    android:id="@+id/tvgesamt"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
    android:layout_height="117dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Abrechnungszeitraum"
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bitte aktualisieren."
        android:id="@+id/tvzeit"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
    android:layout_height="117dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Maximale Geschwindigkeit:"
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bitte aktualisieren."
        android:id="@+id/tvspeed"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <com.faizmalkani.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabbutton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        app:color="#556ffd"/>

</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you know how to do this? I just can't place my TextViews correctly...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            tools:context="com.timbremer.ctdataviewer.MainActivity"
            tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:background="#eeeeee"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



            <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Verbrauchtes Volumen:"
                android:id="@+id/tv1"   />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bitte aktualisieren."
                android:id="@+id/tvused"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"   />
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="117dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"  >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gesamtvolumen:"
                    android:id="@+id/tv2" />

                <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bitte aktualisieren."
                android:id="@+id/tvgesamt"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"  />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_height="117dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout4"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_margin="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Abrechnungszeitraum"
                    android:id="@+id/tv3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bitte aktualisieren."
                    android:id="@+id/tvzeit"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"  />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_height="117dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/frameLayout2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/frameLayout2"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Maximale Geschwindigkeit:"
                    android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bitte aktualisieren."
                    android:id="@+id/tvspeed" />

                <com.faizmalkani.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fabbutton"
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="72dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"  />

            </FrameLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i didnt really read all your xml make this changes....
do this to your FrameLayouts rather

```
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

for top left do this

```
   android:layout_gravity="top|left"
   android:gravity="top|left"
```

and change your frame layouts to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

let me know if i was of help..

Comment: That didn't work too. I solved it. I simply removed and re-pasted the text view and anything was ok :D
But thank you anyways!

Comment: ayt..its all good if you've get passed your problem @tbremer19 happy coding